# Android layout top banner as webview

Tags: android, android-webview, banner-ads

Is it advice able to have top banner/Logo as a webview instead of Image embedded into App? The idea is to control what user see on top using an Adserver

Comment: You should probably add the android tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the ad sdk's seem to use ViewFlippers and ImageViews to rotate the Views that show ads.